# Monte Carlo Method to estimate the probability of the sum of two dice thrown being 7

Tags: python, random, probability, montecarlo

I have tried creating a program in Python where a Monte Carlo method is used to estimate the probability of the sum of two dice being 7.

The result I get is nothing close to the theoretical probability. I just now started coding in Python, so I am struggling to locate where the mistake is. Please let me know!

```
import random
import math


def monte_carlo_estimation():
    sum_seven = 1
    dice_thrown = 1
    prob = 0

    for z in range(0, 100):
        x = random.uniform(1, 6)
        y = random.uniform(1, 6)
        sum_wanted = x + y == 7
        if sum_wanted:
            sum_seven += 1
        dice_thrown += 1
        prob = sum_seven/dice_thrown

    print("Estimate: " + str(prob))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    monte_carlo_estimation()
```

Comment: `random.uniform(1, 6)` returns a float and two floats are rarely going to equal in integer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`random.uniform()` returns a random floating point number. So your dice throws will have fractions, and the sums will practically never be exactly 7.

Since dice can only have integer values, you should use `random.randint(1, 6)` instead of `random.uniform(1, 6)`.

Also you need to initialize your counters to `0`, not `1`. And the line `prob = sum_seven/dice_thrown` should be indented one level less; there's no point in updating it every iteration, since you only care about the final value.

Comment: `prob = sum_seven/dice_thrown` also needs to be tabbed out one level

Comment: It doesn't *need* to be, it's just redundant to update it each time through the loop.

Comment: Yes, de-tabbing the argument does not change the outcome of the code, I even tested it to see if it would.

Comment: Also, when I initialize the counters, setting their values to 0 gives me results with fewer significant figures in the terminal.

Comment: That shouldn't have any effect on the number of significant figures.

Comment: If you initialize to 1, all your counts are 1 more than they should be, so you get the wrong ratio.

Comment: There's little point to `dice_thrown`, it will always be 100 or whatever the limit of the range is.

Comment: Yes, I just added that for readability because it will be graded by a maths teacher, thanks for the help!